# @Test annotation and inheritence

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have Two class

```
public class ClassA
{
    @Test
    public void method1()
    {
      System.out.println("In method1 method of ClassA");
    }

    @Test 
    public void method2()
    {
       System.out.println("In method2 method of ClassA");
    } 
}


public class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    @Test
    public void method3()
    {
       System.out.println("In method3 method of ClassB");
    }
}
```

And my testng.xml

```
<test name="group-test" preserve-order="true" >
     <classes>
        <class name="com.ClassA">
            <methods>
                <include name="method1"/>
                <include name="method2"/> 
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="com.ClassB">
            <methods>
                <include name="method3"/>
            </methods>
            </class>    
    </classes>
</test>
```

After executing the test my output is
In method1 method of ClassA
In method2 method of ClassA
In method3 method of ClassB
In method1 method of ClassA 
In method2 method of ClassA

`method1()` and `method2()` are executing again after `method3()`

Expected output : 
In method1 method of ClassA
In method2 method of ClassA
In method3 method of ClassB

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why `method1()` and `method2()` are executing again after `method3()` ?

Comment: if i write 
    `<class name="com.ClassB">
            <methods>
                <include name="method3"/>
                <exclude name="method1"/>
                <exclude name="method2"/>
           </methods>
     </class>`  
then `method1()` and `method2()` will still execute

Comment: Why don't u execute only class B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour since `ClassB` inherits `method1` and `method2` from `ClassA`.

To get the behavour you want, you should execute only `ClassB` or make `ClassB` not as a child of `ClassA`.

Possible solution:

```
<test name="group-test" preserve-order="true" >
     <classes>
        <class name="com.ClassB">
            <methods>
                <include name="method3"/>
            </methods>
            </class>    
    </classes>
</test>
```

OR:

```
public class ClassB
{
    @Test
    public void method3()
    {
       System.out.println("In method3 method of ClassB");
    }
}
```

maintaining the same XML you provided in your question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @idiazt , i got your point..but in one scenario i have to call method2() from ClassB not from ClassA
 `<class name="com.statictest.ClassB">
  <methods>
   <include name="method2"/>
  </methods>
 </class>` 
but testng totally ignores it.i have mentioned @Test in class level also